# Javascript Estructura For

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Esta secuencia no da los resultados esperados. El resultado de "n" debía ser 512 y no 2 como da según esta escrito.

```js
var n=1;
for (var t1=0;t1<3;t1++){  
  for (var t2=0;t2<3;t2++){ 
    for (var t3=0;t3<3;t3++){  
      for (var t4=0;t4<3;t4++){ 
        for (var t5=0;t5<3;t5++){  
          for (var t6=0;t6<3;t6++){ 
            for (var t7=0;t7<3;t7++){  
              for (var t8=0;t8<3;t8++){
                for (var t9=0;t9<3;t9++){  
                  n=n+1;
                  document.write(n + "<br");
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola @csvicuna , a esta pregunta le falta información , deberías agregar código y que errores tienes.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, como dice Iker Obregón, solo con cerrar la etiqueta <br />.

Cambiando "<br" por "<br/>", se arregla.

Answer (score 2):

Tu codigo, una vez sustituyas tu `<br` por `</br>` va a mostrar todos los numeros desde 0 hasta 19685 o lo que es lo mismo `3^9 + 1`.

Si lo que tu quieres mostrar son los 512 primero numero osea `2^9` deberias de dejar tu codigo asi:

```html
<html>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var n = 0;
    for (var t1 = 0; t1 < 2; t1++) {
      for (var t2 = 0; t2 < 2; t2++) {
        for (var t3 = 0; t3 < 2; t3++) {
          for (var t4 = 0; t4 < 2; t4++) {
            for (var t5 = 0; t5 < 2; t5++) {
              for (var t6 = 0; t6 < 2; t6++) {
                for (var t7 = 0; t7 < 2; t7++) {
                  for (var t8 = 0; t8 < 2; t8++) {
                    for (var t9 = 0; t9 < 2; t9++) {
                      n = n + 1;
                      document.write(n  + "</br>");
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  </script>

</html>
```

Y si solo quieres mostrar el 512 asi:

```html
<html>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var n = 0;
    for (var t1 = 0; t1 < 2; t1++) {
      for (var t2 = 0; t2 < 2; t2++) {
        for (var t3 = 0; t3 < 2; t3++) {
          for (var t4 = 0; t4 < 2; t4++) {
            for (var t5 = 0; t5 < 2; t5++) {
              for (var t6 = 0; t6 < 2; t6++) {
                for (var t7 = 0; t7 < 2; t7++) {
                  for (var t8 = 0; t8 < 2; t8++) {
                    for (var t9 = 0; t9 < 2; t9++) {
                      n = n + 1;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    document.write(n  + "</br>");

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Iker, con esa solución. Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Podrias macar la respuesta como correcta, asi podria ayudar a alguien que preguntara algo similar.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta cerrar la etiqueta `<br />`.

Cambia "`<br`" por "`<br/>`"

Luego, si mal no entendí. Solo queres que muestre 1 valor. Deberías añadir ese valor en una variable, y al final de todos los `for` imprimir esa variable.

Comment: Gracias, Alexander. Es verdad que cerrando la etiqueta. Funciona perfectamente.